# Is it possible to unit test, php files other than class file using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to PHPUnit. I have php files that don't have any classes in them. What I came to understand from reading documentation, PHPUnit considers a class as a single unit.
So **Does PHPUnit considers a class as a unit?**
**Is it possible to test php files that don't have any class in them?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can absolutely test other PHP scripts.

```
class MyScriptTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testMyFunction() {
        include_once 'path/to/script.php';
        $result = someFunction();

        $this->assertEquals('expected result', $result);
    }
}
```

So write PHPUnit test classes, and inside a test run whatever code you wish to test and make assertions against it.